# Are there any examples of applying machine learning to improve code performance?

Tags: performance, machine-learning, performance-testing

I saw a [talk](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/facebook-tuning) by Keith Adams of Facebook comparing machine learning techniques to tuning code for improved performance in the real world. Are there examples of such automation techniques being applied in real projects? I

I know of profile guided optimizations in certain compilers and also some techniques JIT compilers use to improve performance, but I am thinking of more fundamental ways to improve code performance that could require changing the code itself and not code generation. Things like:

1. Choosing the optimal buffer size in a particular network application or choosing the right stack size for particular application.
2. Selecting the struct layout in a multi-threaded application that improves local cache performance while reducing false sharing.
3. Selecting different data structures all together for a certain algorithm.

I read a [paper](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jrk/halide-pldi13.pdf) on Halide, an image processing framework that uses genetic algorithms to auto-tune image processing pipelines to improve performance. Examples like this one or any pointers to research would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFTW is a widely used software package which uses OCaml to generate optimized C code. This paper has more details on the process: http://vuduc.org/pubs/vuduc2000-fftw-dct.pdf

You might also look into Acovea, a genetic algorithm to optimize compiler flags: http://stderr.org/doc/acovea/html/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Remy http://web.mit.edu/remy/
It uses kind of genetic optimization approach to generate algorithm for congestion control in networks, significantly increasing network's performance. One specifies assumptions about network being used, and Remy generates control algorithm to be run on data nodes of this network. The results are amazing, Remy outperforms all human-developed so far optimization techniques.